# Scala type inference can't mix values and references?

Tags: scala

I'm using some Java API from Scala, which looks like :

```
public Boolean isBoolValue();
public Boolean getBoolValue();
```

And the type inference engine seems to have troubles with it, like so :

```
val fetchedValue = if (isBoolValue()) getBoolValue() else false
```

The inferred type is `Any`. How come? Or am I holding it wrong? 
I know that the compiler sometimes choses unexpected types sometimes when there are different thinggies for the `then` and the `else` branch, here we have booleans everywhere.

Of course my example works if I change `getBoolValue` to return `boolean` (which I obviously can't, being an API) or if I add type annotation to fetchedValue.

Is there also a nicer way then specifying the expected type for the `if` expression?

They say Scala doesn't have two booleans, two ints etc like Java but my example seems to prove that somehow there are two flavors of these primitives?

Comment: You could do: `val fetchedValue = if (isBoolValue()) getBoolValue().booleanValue() else false`, or simplify it to `val fetchedValue = isBoolValue() && getBoolValue.booleanValue()`

Comment: yup, and even `val fetchedValue = isBoolValue() && getBoolValue()` works. This is nice enoungh already. Waiting now for someone to hopefuly give pointers as to what happens inside scalac with that initial `if`

Comment: I believe `val fetchedValue: Boolean = if (isBoolValue()) getBoolValue() else false` also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
val fetchedValue = if (isBoolValue()) getBoolValue() else false:java.lang.Boolean
```

but your problem is that `false` (in scala) isn't of type `java.lang.Boolean` so `Any` is correct.

> They say Scala doesn't have two booleans, two ints etc like Java but my example seems to prove that somehow there are two flavors of these primitives?

No, it's the other way about. Scala has one, but Java has two, and the one Scala one can't be the same type as both the Java ones...

Comment: ok..  Makes sense. Sometimes Scala has plain aliases over java equivalents (`String`, `BigDecimal` to an extent) hence I somehow wrongly considered this is the case here. Still there is some inconsistency IMO since the compiler accepted the `public Boolean getBoolValue();` API variant without a hint of a missmatch

Comment: "since the compiler accepted the `public Boolean getBoolValue();`" Not sure what you mean there. That's a Java statement not a Scala one

Comment: sorry; I ment to say : scala's compiler accepted the `public boolean getBoolValue()` version of the API (the if expression was infered to have Boolean type) and did not succeed wrt to `public Boolean getBoolValue()`, where it inferred `Any`. Possibly java's boolean is considered to be subtype of `AnyVal` while `Boolean` subtype of `AnyRef`, ruling out any reconciliation between these two

Comment: Yes exactly. One is a value type one is a reference type